# Construct regex expression in objective c

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have an NSString object of the form

```
"this is [i]1[/i] and that is [i]2[/i] and there we have [i]3[/i], and so on"
```

The [i]1[/i] is a reference to image number 1 located somewhere. I want to use regex match and replace to obtain the following output:

```
"this is <img src="root/1.png"> and that is <img src="root/2.png"> and there we have <img src="root/3.png">, and so on"
```

I use a `NSRegularExpression` class but I think my regex construction is wrong. Please help.

Comment: \\[[i]\\][0-9]+\\[\\[i]\\]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to properly escape the brackets. You have to escape them *twice*. A single backslash will be interpreted by the Objective-C compiler as a string escape character. To insert a backslash into the regexp pattern, you have to escape it, i.e. to match `[` you have to write `\\[`.

```
NSString *string = @"this is [i]1[/i] and that is [i]2[/i] and there we have [i]3[/i], and so on";
NSString *pattern = @"\\[i\\]([0-9]+)\\[/i\\]";
NSString *replacement = @"<img src=\"root/$1.png\">";
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern 
                               options:0 error:nil];
NSString *replaced = [regexp stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string 
                                           options:0 
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) 
                                      withTemplate:replacement];
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did not escape the brackets properly.